# How do you get a green cheek conure to stop screeching so much?

Tags: birds, vocalizations, parrots

I have a 8yr old pineapple green cheek conure (most likely male). Since losing his cage mate 2 years ago he has become needier (more frequent, nosier screeching). He is will taken care of. We let him out of his cage for a few hours a day, feed him mostly pellets and fresh fruit. We spend as much time with him as we can. But he screeches a lot throughout the day. I know I can't eliminate natural bird behavior but is there a way to minimize this?

Comment: Does he see a vet regularly? The most natural would be a new partner for him. Is this an option for you?

Comment: We had a Bolivian Green Macaw, small but loud. When the phone rang he would shrike for a half hour.  We corrected it by giving him away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does he stop when he’s with you? It may be because he’s lonely and looking for his friend. Try rewarding him when he’s quiet and leave the room when he begins to squawk. Make sure he has loads of toys in his cage to keep himself busy when you're not around.

I’d also maybe think about getting him a new friend, because birds hate living alone and it will definitely cheer him up.

I’ve owned a few birds and in my experience all these methods have worked. Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE :) Maybe you can short mention a source where your knowledge comes from. For example some kind of book or website. Own experience also counts as source.